# Ubuntu for phones - is there a terminal similar to the one known from PC's?

Tags: command-line, bash, filesystem, ubuntu-touch

I am thinking about install Ubuntu **on a phone**.

I spend a lot of time in terminal while working on my PC. There are much things I do using bash scripts, for example. Then, is there a terminal on Ubuntu for phones? Does it work with bash? Are commands similar to standard Unix commands (like *ls*, *touch*, *echo*, *mkdir*, ...)?

Is the filesystem similar to ext3 or other Linux-like? Does it depend on phone model?

Finishing, I mean I want not to get used to new things, such as new file systems, new terminals, new commands, etc... Just want to have old good Ubuntu on my phone.

Thanks for answer!

Comment: I think that there should be .... but no idea because I haven't used it yet!

Comment: Which part of "There will be a developer image for download at the end of February." is misleading you to the assumption that anyone could possibly know by now? :P

Since it is actually a real Ubuntu sitting on top of Android Kernels I strongly think so.

Comment: " Just want to have old good Ubuntu on my phone" - No, you will have good ol' Ubuntified Android.

Comment: Hook up a keyboard for maximum efficiency

Answer (score 2):

There is a fully functional Terminal app in the Ubuntu store, and the Nexus device images come with it pre-isntalled. It is based on the KDE terminal app's components, and gives you a normal Bash shell just like you would expect on a desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu for phone will have terminal emulators, as for a tty that might be another thing but quite possible it will have a tty as well. This is speculation of course however the nexus 7 images has gnome-terminal by default. and you can install any terminal and use it from the repository. So would stand to reason the phone will as well.

Comment: Where did you get the image?

Comment: @rafalcieslak https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7 will have all the details you need.

Comment: AAh, right. I had an impression you meant UbuntuPhoneOS images, while you were refferring to a tablet :-)

Comment: no pretty sure I said nexus 7 image.